# What hook for product image replacement in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

What function is called when WooCommerce returns image for products in shop page? I would like to replace image with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out, you need look at [`content-product.php` template source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/templates/content-product.php#L36-L42) from line 36 to 42:

```
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

So when looking at [`woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail()` involved hooked template function source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1310-L1319), you will see that it uses [`woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1348-L1365):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {

    /**
     * Get the product thumbnail, or the placeholder if not set.
     *
     * @param string $size (default: 'woocommerce_thumbnail').
     * @param int    $deprecated1 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0).
     * @param int    $deprecated2 Deprecated since WooCommerce 2.0 (default: 0).
     * @return string
     */
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail', $deprecated1 = 0, $deprecated2 = 0 ) {
        global $product;

        $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );

        return $product ? $product->get_image( $image_size ) : '';
    }
}
```

---

**So to make changes** you will have to replace `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail()` hooked function by a custom one this way:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
function custom_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product ) {    
        // your code for image replacement below (to be echoed)
    }
}
```

To target shop pages only, you will use `is_shop()` conditional tag.